# Wget Mirror HTML only

Tags: wget, scrape, mirror

I have a small website that I try to mirror to my local machine with only the html file, no images, image attach files... pdf, ..etc.

I have never mirrored a website before and think it would be a good idea to ask the question before doing anything catastrophical.

This is the command that I want to run and wondering if anything else should be added.

```
wget --mirror <url>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `-R` and `-A` options are used to *reject* or *accept* specific file types.

Also consider the bandwidth used to download a whole website. You may want to add the `--random-wait` option as well.

If you want to skip all images and pdfs, your command will look something like:

```
wget --mirror --random-wait -R gif,jpg,pdf <url>
```

**Note: mirroring a website may go against the policy, so I suggest you check first.**

Sources:

- [GNU Wget Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options)
- [Wget Recursive Accept/Reject Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options)

Answer (score 2):

There are also wget patches that add mimetypes filtering options ...